# How can I detect Windows Authentication Prompts with Selenium web driver?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, windows-authentication, f5

I have a C# script to test some SharePoint sites.

We are getting prompts to reauthenticate on some pages when using IE.
(We suspect it is something to do with our F5 load balancer)

I want to be able to create a script that can visit pages and then let me know if the page had a Windows Authentication Prompt?
At the moment I don't need to login through the prompt just detect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait and catch the alert.

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("url_where_your_WAP_is");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));

IAlert simpleAlert = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
simpleAlert.SetAuthenticationCredentials("user", "password");
```

Comment: This has worked well so far just added 
simpleAlert.Accept(); for when I needed it to log in.

Comment: This will not work. Navigate().GoToUrl() blocks, waiting until the credentials have been entered, so the following code will never execute. You will get a timeout exception.

Comment: I also get the timeout. Is there a solution?