# GoToUrl() hangs

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a test that I use driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("...") to navigate to the home page but I believe the domain throws in a login page so the initial GoToUrl() just hangs waiting for authentication window (asking for username and password) to be closed. So two questions. One, how do I tell that the authentication is being displayed? Two, how do I interact with this box (input the user name and password) when I cannot even see the source to the dialog box using Chrome developer tools? I have seen some answers such as [How can I detect Windows Authentication Prompts with Selenium web driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288057/how-can-i-detect-windows-authentication-prompts-with-selenium-web-driver) but I still get this timeout before I can wait for an alert.  So the full code that I am trying looks like:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("url_where_your_WAP_is");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));

IAlert simpleAlert = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
simpleAlert.SetAuthenticationCredentials("user", "password");
```

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of login page are you using (doe it look like it is part of the page, or is a boring grey pop-up thing)? What kind of authentication is the website using?

Comment: The login is a Windows Authentication login. My suspicion is that the URL redirects to another page that causes the Windows Authentication to popup. Since this Windows Authentication is not answered (or even if it was) the "response" to the page request is a redirect and I am not sure how to follow this redirect chain (especially when there is a Windows Authentication in the chain somewhere) with Selenium/